# Getting 'Invalid query' error when doing name='test' to Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am using PyDrive to fetch list of file names from a Google Drive folder

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = r"client_secrets.json"

gauth = GoogleAuth(settings_file='settings.yaml')

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

folder_id = "folder-id"

file_list = drive.ListFile(
{
    'q': "name = 'test'",
    'supportsAllDrives': True, 
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True, 
}
).GetList()
```

The syntax `name = 'test'` I saw from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

I am getting error

```
oogleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=name%3D%27test%27&maxResults=1000&alt=json returned "Invalid query". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid query', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'q'}]">
```

If I fetch all file names, it works perfectly

```
'q': f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"
```

My goal is to check if file with specific name exists or not in a particular folder, something like `name = 'file-name' and 'folder-id' in parents and trashed=false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the script of pydrive, it seems that Drive API v2 is used. [Ref](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive/blob/42022f9a1c48f435438fce74ad4032ec9f34cfd1/pydrive/auth.py#L523) In the case of Drive API v2, the metadata of filename is `title`. I thought that this might be the reason of your current issue of `Invalid query`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
'q': "name = 'test'",
```

#### To:

```
"q": "title = 'test'",
```

#### Note:

- About `'q': f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"`, in this case, both Drive API v2 and v3 can be used. By this, I think that no error occurs.

#### Reference:

- [PyDrive](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive)